# Cause of strange BIOS behavior that fails Windows 7 boot?

Tags: windows-7, bios

I've noticed two problems which may or may not be inter-related.

1. Windows 7 does not start; it freezes on a black screen after the logo splash screen.  It can, however, load in safe mode with networking.
2. With or without the hard drive, there is a screen after the initial boot with many zeroes in a diagonal and other text is skewed (see picture):

This started happening after a Windows crash and reboot.  I have not yet tried loading an OS with a Live CD.  The motherboard is an EVGA P55 LE for Intel's LGA 1156.

Is the BIOS strangeness the cause of the Windows 7 problem?  If so, what could fix this problem before I try to reinstall Windows?

[image: BIOS screen with zeroes.]

Comment: Wow, that looks hosed. I'd try first swapping out the video adapter; the boot behavior described (OK in safe mode, fails in normal mode) makes it sound like the video card may have partially lost its mind, such that it can come up in VESA standard 640x480 mode, but can't handle the higher-resolution mode Windows tries to switch into when it loads the real video driver (which doesn't happen in safe mode). Failing that, I'd try reflashing the motherboard BIOS.

Comment: Test your memory modules...http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: Do what Moab said, first run memtest, see if there's anything wrong with the RAM, if not, then you can also power down your computer completely, and remove the CMOS battery on your motherboard. Unplug the power cord when you do and press the power button a few times to completely get rid of any residual electricity in the circuits. Let it stand for 10 mins and then try booting up again.

Comment: @Aaron Swapping out the video card did it.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it.  I also ran memtest for good measure and (luckily) no more errors were found.

Comment: Answer made, and glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that looks hosed. I'd try first swapping out the video adapter; the boot behavior described (OK in safe mode, fails in normal mode) makes it sound like the video card may have partially lost its mind, such that it can come up in VESA standard 640x480 mode, but can't handle the higher-resolution mode Windows tries to switch into when it loads the real video driver (which doesn't happen in safe mode). Failing that, I'd try reflashing the motherboard BIOS.